# Modify Javascript Variable Using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, variables, greasemonkey

Help, can anyone help me how to change javascript variable using greasemonkey?

I already following the answers on this question:
[How can I change a JavaScript variable using Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722075/how-can-i-change-a-javascript-variable-using-greasemonkey)

and also this link:
http://webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=166658

but I unable to modify the **counter variable value** on the function with this script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      https://welcome.telkomhotspot.info/telkomhs/freemax/
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==

unsafeWindow.counter = 1;
```

Here are the function that I want to change:

```
function startTimer(){
var counter = 20;
var wait = 0;
var displayCounter = true;
var startCounting = false;
$("#timerTransition").html(getLoadingCounter())
.everyTime(1000,function(i){
    if(wait==0){
        if(displayCounter){
            $("#loadingCounter").fadeOut(500,function(){
                $("#timerTransition").html(getTimerContainer(counter));
                $("#timerContainer").fadeIn(500,function(){
                    startCounting = true;
                });
            });
        }
        displayCounter = false;
        if(startCounting){
            counter = counter - 1;
            $("#counter").html(counter);
            if(counter == 0) {

                if(foundCookies){
                    $("#timerTransition").stopTime().html(getAuthCookiesLogin());
                }
                else{
                    $("#timerTransition").stopTime().html(getAuthButton());
                    $("#authBtnContainer").fadeIn(0).click(function(){
                        $(this).fadeOut(0);
                        closeAds();
                        openAuthForm();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        wait = wait-1;
    }
});
}
```

Thanks for helping, I already searching on google but still I can't modify the variable.

Comment: If you define `unsafeWindow.counter` you should also read `unsafeWindow.counter` so replace `counter` with `unsafeWindow.counter` everywhere.

Comment: Did you mean, replace all `counter` with `unsafeWindow.counter`? But I don't have an access to the file. I want to modify the counter variable **value** from `counter = 20;` with `counter = 1;` on some website using Greasemonkey, so I can skip the **timer** more quickly. Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter` is a local variable within a function. You will not be able to change its value unless you can modify the function to use a global variable.  If you do not have access to the code, you could try replacing the entire `startTimer` function with your own implementation.  I can not tell from your example, but you can only replace startTimer if it is a global.

Comment: Thanks @mikerobi, I'm trying to replace the function with new simple script on this website: [link](http://www.squakmt.com/replacing_javascript/index.htm). but the `startTimer` function on `idconnect.js` file still being called by the page.

Well, i must say I'm still new with Greasemonkey.

Comment: @yudayyy, I forgot to mention, you can only replace startTimer if it is a global as well.

Comment: so, it mean I cannot override the function on `idconnect.js` right?